# Blog API with DRF getting Anonymous User Error

Tags: django, api, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am creating a BlogAPI with LoginAPI(using dj-rest-auth). I have created a model for my Post-

models.py

```
        from django.db import models
        from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    
        class Post(models.Model):
        content = models.TextField()
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then I have made 2 serializers User and Post -

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Post
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'id', 'email']


class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['user', 'content']
```

My view looks like this-

views.py

```
from rest_framework import viewsets, permissions
from .serializers import UserSerializer, PostSerializer, CommentSerializer
from . import models
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import action, api_view, permission_classes


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = PostSerializer(
            data=request.data, context={'request': request})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        print(request.data)
        print(request.user)

        serializer.save(user=request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

I have kept the permissions_class as AllowAny because then I was not able to test the API.

urls.py(inside app)

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'^users', views.UserViewSet)
router.register(r'^posts', views.PostViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    re_path(r'^posts/(?P<pk>\d+)/comments/$', view=views.PostViewSet.as_view({'get': 'comments', 'post': 'comments'})),
    re_path(r'^posts/(?P<pk>\d+)/comments/(?P<comment>\d+)/$', view=views.PostViewSet.as_view({'delete': 'remove_comment'}))
]
```

After running it on locahost on http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/ I am able to do GET and see all posts by all users but after Posting, I am getting this error-

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: POST Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/
>
> Django Version: 4.0.6 Python Version: 3.8.9 Installed Applications:
> ['django.contrib.admin',  'django.contrib.auth',
> 'django.contrib.contenttypes',  'django.contrib.sessions',
> 'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles',  'ApiApp',
> 'rest_framework',  'rest_framework.authtoken',  'dj_rest_auth',
> 'django.contrib.sites',  'allauth',  'allauth.account',
> 'allauth.socialaccount',  'dj_rest_auth.registration'] Installed
> Middleware: ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
> 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
> 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
> 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
> 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
> 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
> 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/shlokabhalgat/PycharmProjects/TestAssignmentAPI/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
> line 55, in inner
> response = get_response(request)   File "/Users/shlokabhalgat/PycharmProjects/TestAssignmentAPI/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
> line 197, in _get_response
> response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "/Users/shlokabhalgat/PycharmProjects/TestAssignmentAPI/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py",
> line 54, in wrapped_view
> return view_func(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/shlokabhalgat/PycharmProjects/TestAssignmentAPI/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py",
> line 125, in view
> return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/shlokabhalgat/PycharmProjects/TestAssignmentAPI/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py",
> line 509, in dispatch
> response = self.handle_exception(exc)   File "/Users/shlokabhalgat/PycharmProjects/TestAssignmentAPI/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py",
> line 469, in handle_exception
> self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)   File "/Users/shlokabhalgat/PycharmProjects/TestAssignmentAPI/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py",
> line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
> raise exc   File "/Users/shlokabhalgat/PycharmProjects/TestAssignmentAPI/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py",
> line 506, in dispatch
> response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/shlokabhalgat/PycharmProjects/TestAssignmentAPI/ApiApp/views.py",
> line 29, in create
> serializer.save(user=request.user)   File "/Users/shlokabhalgat/PycharmProjects/TestAssignmentAPI/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py",
> line 212, in save
> self.instance = self.create(validated_data)   File "/Users/shlokabhalgat/PycharmProjects/TestAssignmentAPI/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py",
> line 962, in create
> instance = ModelClass._default_manager.create(**validated_data)   File
> "/Users/shlokabhalgat/PycharmProjects/TestAssignmentAPI/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py",
> line 85, in manager_method
> return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/shlokabhalgat/PycharmProjects/TestAssignmentAPI/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py",
> line 512, in create
> obj = self.model(**kwargs)   File "/Users/shlokabhalgat/PycharmProjects/TestAssignmentAPI/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py",
> line 541, in **init**
> _setattr(self, field.name, rel_obj)   File "/Users/shlokabhalgat/PycharmProjects/TestAssignmentAPI/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py",
> line 235, in **set**
> raise ValueError(
>
> Exception Type: ValueError at /posts/ Exception Value: Cannot assign
> "<django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x103243910>":
> "Post.user" must be a "User" instance.

How should I pass the user as foreign key in seriliazers.py and get an authenticated user for POST?